# Checking if "other" users is logged in/ logged out using Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-5

I am creating an application that is similar to a chat application.

I wish to be able to determine if a user is logged in or not.

The way I am doing this is by having a `is_logged_in` field in the `users` table.

However I am unsure in how to update this variable, as I don't know what method is called during `logout`.

I assume it would be something like this:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    //...
    public function login($user)
    {
        $user->is_logged_in = true;
        $user->save();
    }

    public function logout($user)
    {
        $user->is_logged_in = false;
        $user->save();
    }

    //...
}
```

Of course the `login` and `logout` aren't the methods that run when the user actually logs in and logs out, but I am unsure as to where to put the logic.

### Update

These are the routes for authentication.

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin')->name('postLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout')->name('logout');

Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister')->name('postRegister');
```

**EDIT**
I am aware that I can check if current user is authenticated using:

```
Auth::check()
```

However, this does not help determine if OTHER users are logged in or not

Comment: You can use Session::set() and Session::get() methods to handle the login.And finally can use Session::flush() method in Laravel to logout the user.

Comment: I think that's a poor solution compared to mine, as there is a lot of logic in the  Authentication trait that does not run. Also It's a lot more complex compared to using events!

Answer (score 1):

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
   //...
   public function login($user)
   {
      // You can choose to check if the user is logged in
      // before you authenticate the user but its not really necessary because it can cause issues
      if(Auth::check()){
        // user is logged in
      }else{
         if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
           // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
         }
      }
   }

   public function logout($user)
   {
     if(!Auth::check()){
       // user is logged out
     }else{
       Auth::logout();
     }
   }

}
```

**Edited**

I guess you want to know were the authentication really happens(laravel 5.2)

You can check the **AuthenticatesUsers** Trait. That is were the getLogin() function get called

Comment: I don't think that works, as those methods don't even run! I put `dd("hi`)` at the top of the methods, and they did not run! The example in my code was just an example. I need a place to put my code

Comment: How did you log in the user

Comment: using `Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin')->name('login');` and I didn't create a method called "getLogin". It did it automatically!

Comment: use this to log in if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}

Comment: Can u put it in ur answer as I can't see it properly informatted

Comment: But the `login` and `logout` methods don't even run. they were just examples. the problem is that I don't know where to put the code. See my routes

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Edit User Controller [NOT RECOMMENDED]**

After some close examination of the `AuthicatesUsers` trait I managed to fix this issue:

I added the following method to the `User` Model;

```
public function authenticated($request, User $user) {
    $user->is_logged_in = true;
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}

public function getLogout()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->is_logged_in = false;
        $user->save();
    }

    Auth::logout()
    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

**Solution 2: Use Events [RECOMMENDED]**

I found that Solution 1 is perhaps not the best way, as there are other ways a user can login (e.g. social authentication).

Therefore it is better to use events. i.e. Add these to the `EventServiceProvider` `boot`  method:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    $events->listen('auth.login', function (User $user, $remember) {
        $user->is_logged_in = true;
        $user->save();
    });

    $events->listen('auth.logout', function (User $user) {
        $user->is_logged_in = false;
        $user->save();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a chat application and you want to know if another user is logged in (or, more specifically, actively available for chats), you are best off using an event based approach using a service like Pusher to identify specific users that are listening on a given channel. The database is never an effective place to track a user's logged in status, as a user can simply close their browser, effectively making them logged out, but the database will not know about it. You can do something like look at a user's last activity and update that on every request, but this type of method would not account for a user that sits idle for a long amount of time without logging out, but is still available for chat. The system would look at their last action time and think they were logged out, when they're not.

So the only thing you can do reliably is to have an event broadcast channel open and then all other clients would have access to see the other active "listeners" to the channel. When a user closes their browser, it closes their connection to the channel, which then immediately propagates to all the other users. If you don't know about these types of event based channel capabilities built into Laravel, I'd really suggest you watch [Jeffrey Way's laracasts on Laravel Echo](https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo). It's easier to implement on newer versions of Laravel, but very powerful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel documentation found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating).

> Determining If The Current User Is Authenticated
>
> To determine if the user is already logged into your application, you
>   may use the check method on the Auth facade, which will return true if
>   the user is authenticated:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in... 
}
```

Comment: But it won't help in determining if other users are logged in. I'm creating like a chat application.